# JQuery - add class if element has class

Tags: jquery, animation, addclass

I want to add class to elements which have class 'alignleft'. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.foto').children().hasClass('alignleft')){
        $(this).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    }
});
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. However if I use `$('.foto').children().addClass('animated bounceInLeft');` it applies class to all child elements with class 'alignleft'. So the problem is in `$(this)` maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this`, which refers the window object. Instead use the the class as selector in **[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** method.

```
$('.foto').children('.alignleft').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
```

Or use [child selector(`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('.foto > .alignleft').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target elements using class selector and then add classes to them:

```
$('.foto .alignleft').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var elem = $('.foto .alignleft');
  if (elem) {
    elem.addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
  }
});
```

---

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.foto .alignleft').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var elem = $('.foto .alignleft');
  if (elem) {
    elem.addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
  }
});
```

```css
.alignleft{color:red;}
.alignright{color:green;}

.animated{background:lightgrey;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foto">
  <div class="alignleft">
    Div A
  </div>
  
  <div class="alignleft">
    Div B
  </div>
  
  <div class="alignright">
    Div C
  </div>
   <div class="alignright">
    Div D
  </div>
</div>
```